# The King's Routes Problem: How many possibilities?

Tags: combinatorics, chess

On a chessboard, a king is to be allowed to move one square at a time: horizontally to the right, vertically downward, or diagonally to the right and downward. Imagine a reduced 4x4 chessboard, with the king beginning in the top-left square. By how many routes can he reach the bottom-right square? By how many routes can a similar journey be made on a full 8x8 chessboard?

Comment: VTC: This is a typical combinatorics textbook problem, not a puzzle.

Comment: As a starter puzzle for those less familiar with puzzling, I think it has merit. Textbook problems are a way for beginners to get into puzzling.